# Xpath for finding text inside of an anchor tag using class (Scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract the link of Anchor Tag using Xpath

URL

```html
<a class="text size-1x-small font-accent color-brand all-caps"
   href="http://time.com/section/business" 
   data-reactid="199">
       Business
</a>
```

Code

```py
item["category"] = str(
    response.xpath(
        '//a[@class="text size-1x-small font-accent color-brand all-caps"]/text()'
    ).extract()
    )
```

And the python function

```py
def parseSave(self, response):
    item = NYtimesItem()
    item["category"] = response.xpath(
        '//a[@class="text size-1x-small font-accent color-brand all-caps"]/text()'
    ).extract()

    yield item
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong
The expected output would be the text of Anchor Tag. e.g Business

Comment: What is the URL you're on? Also, there is no need to call `str` on the result.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the response properly? When I use your XPath it returns `['Business']` (i.e. in a list). If you just want the string, use `.get()` instead of `.extract()`.

Comment: If you're not getting anything, post the rest of your code.

Comment: After observing my response it seems that some of the links has given me "values" and some are not because of the old structure 

because in their old links they are getting same thing from different css class

I am adding my code

Comment: So you just need to use different selectors for different links?

Comment: Do you think i need to write an if statement to check if a selector is giving me some response . if its not i should get response from other selector ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189251/discussion-between-adnan-and-malberts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/text()` is meant to get the element's inner text. To extract the href attribute use `/@href` instead.

[Here is a handy xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath#steps)